# Thunderbird: enable drag and drop to move email into folder

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

I recently did a fresh install to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.  I have thunderbird 14.0

Thunderbird isn't letting me move an email to a folder by dragging it.  How do I turn this [back] on?  Or is this a bug?

One note (that may be important): I saved my .thunderbird folder from my 11.10 install and moved it over the default folder (so as to not need to set up everything again).

Comment: Try this [Add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/disable-draganddrop-thunderbir/)

Comment: @Mitch That's the opposite of what I want.  That addon seems to be made to disable drag and drop.  I want to *enable* it.  BTW, I did double check and that add on is not currently installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an update and reboot, it is now working.